# When past states contain useful information, does A3C perform better than TD3, given that TD3 does not use an LSTM?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, comparison, long-short-term-memory, actor-critic-methods, a3c

I am trying to build an AI that needs to have some information about the past states as well. Therefore, LSTMs are suitable for this.

Now, I want to know that for a problem/game like Breakout, where we require previous states as well, does A3C perform better than [TD3](https://www.mathworks.com/help/reinforcement-learning/ug/td3-agents.html), given that TD3 does not have LSTM?

Or without the LSTM TD3 should perform better than A3C despite the fact that A3C has LSTM in it.